# URL Rewrite to https on certain URLs

Tags: http, https, url-rewriting

I need to redirect http requests, to https. But only when my site is accessed via the normal URL. i.e. [www.accufinance.com](http://www.accufinance.com)

When I access it in debug, locally, I connect using localhost - and don't want the rewrite to happen (As I don't have SSL locally).

I am trying this:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^accufinance.com$" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But the rewrite rule doesn't happen. If I use (.*) as the match URL, it works fine, but catches ALL connections. How can I make the rule only fire when there is 'accufinance.com' in the URL?

Comment: Is this an htaccess file? I've not seen this exact syntax before, though it looks similar.. If not, what type of file is it? I do not see any other technology mentioned in the tags? Thx. (I have a similar question, but for use in an `.htaccess` file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `HTTP_HOST` with a condition to match your domain name.
The directive `match` for `url` param only contains what's after your domain name.

Example: `http://www.domain.tld/some/url/here.ext`

- `HTTP_HOST` = `www.domain.tld`
- `REQUEST_URI` = `/some/url/here.ext`

You can use this rule to do what you want

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?accufinance\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Please note you'll need to clear your browser's cache before trying again (your old rule is still in cache because of your permanent redirect)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression `^accufinance.com$` is extremely restrictive. The `^` indicates that it must match all the way to the beginning (i.e. nothing else precedes it), and the `$` requires that nothing follow it all the way to the end. As such, the match will only succeed when the request URL is exactly `accufinance.com`.

Try removing the `^` and `$`. Or, you can explicitly allow parts of the URL before and after the desired filter, as in `.*accufinance\.com.*`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this - <match url=".*accufinance\.com.*" ignoreCase="true"/> - but still, it doesn't redirect to https. Do I need the 'dot' and the 'slash'?

Comment: Also - <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/> - works, but  ... I don't want it to redirect when the url is localhost, or anything else.